# Maximum NDVI greenest pixel composites to create cloud free Landsat 8 images

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat-8, composite

I am utilizing maximum NDVI to get the greenest pixel of Landsat 8 data to create cloud free composites in the Google Earth Engine.

I found this GEE tutorial which is using Landsat 8 Top of Atmosphere collection `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA` to create the greenest pixel: [Mapping NDVI over a function](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/tutorial_api_06)

I created a script in the GEE and it works pretty good! [GEE - Greenest pixel Landsat 8 TOA](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8673ccbfd7c0075c79e5fab615b1d2e5)

Here is the AOI asset [AOI](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-julianistrue/assets/PNG_Upstream_Area_buffer250m)

However I would like to get my final result with the Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance collection `LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2`. I created a script for that too but the result is very poor. Somehow the image is really cloudy and the greenest pixel approach does not work. I can't figure out why. The difference between the two collections in "only" the atmospheric correction... Unfortunately the approach of using greenest pixel to get cloud free composites is apparently not really common. I did not find anything useful during my research. I am convinced by the idea though!

GEE script for L8 SR: [GEE - Greenest Pixel Landsat 8 SR](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1f484530e395963346590323d732499d)

**My question: Why does the Surface Reflectance result include these clouds in contrast to the result of TOA and how can I correct it?** (The whole idea of this method is to have no clouds)

Here is a screenshot of the cloud free L8 TOA result.

[image: Greenest pixel L8 TOA]

Here is the result of the L8 Surface Reflectance. You can see the "green clouds"...

[image]